# How to set the URL after using $_SESSION to store data submitted across multi pages in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Session Form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="get" action="session_php.php">
    Add text using session<input type="text" name="formdata" size="20">
    <input type="submit" value="Press to submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<?php
session_start();
if (isset ($_GET['formdata'] ))
{
  
      $_SESSION['times'] = $_SESSION['times']+1;
      // a better way
      // $_SESSION['times']++;
   $_SESSION['data'] = $_GET['formdata'];
      $_SESSION['old'] = $_SESSION['old']."<br>".$_SESSION['data'];
   echo $_SESSION['old']."<br>";
      echo "times changed = ".$_SESSION['times']."<br>";
   
}
else
{
     echo "No data was submitted<br>";
}
?>
```

Hi all,
I am a new in php and recently I met a problem.

When I use the $_SESSION to store the data(e.g. I typed 'dddd')passed from the html page, the URL of submitted page changes to 'session_php.php?formdata=dddd'.

While if I use the original URL 'session_php.php', it turns out 'No data was submitted'.

How to set the correct URL which contains the stored data.

Thanks for helping,

Comment: Just wondering, why are you using GET instead of POST? POST will be the better option instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for that follow this

```
www.somewebsite.com?somevariable=<?php echo $_SESSION['data']; ?>
```

that's it..

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering how to set the link  if there are several variables passed from the previous page?

Answer (score 1):

Every data will be stored in $_SESSION[] variable like this

```
$_SESSIOM['data1'],  $_SESSIOM['data2'],  $_SESSIOM['data3']
```

Answer (score 0):

The url pattern you have given is

```
session_php.php?formdata=dddd
```

session_php.php is the file name and then a "?" after that a form field name "formdata" the "=" then a value "dddd"

you just change the "dddd" to what ever you want and will become your data 
just write it like this

```
session_php.php?formdata=value1
session_php.php?formdata=value2
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I am wondering how to set a link that can dynamically direct to the page showing the final submission?

Answer (score 0):

The `$_GET` super variable will store values which are passed as part of the url.

In the case of `?formdata=dddd` you will have `$_GET['formdata']` = `(string) dddd`

What you are doing, correctly, is passing the value of `$_GET['formdata']` to `$_SESSION['data']` as this will retain the value you passed as part of the GET request.

What you are doing wrong is checking for `isset ($_GET['formdata']` in `session_php.php`. you want to be doing something like this:

```
if (isset ($_SESSION['data']]) {

} else {

}
```

If you are checking the `$_GET` variable then as soon as you string the query string off the URL you have essential unset that variable.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a dynamic link for that. Because you have that submitted value in your session variable. You can call that value in any page you want.

in any page you just write

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['data']; ?>
```

Comment: what if there are more than two data passed except $_SESSION[‘data’]